# Why Random::nextInt not allowed in java as method reference?

Tags: java, java-8

So I was reading generics and functional interfaces. There were two ways shown - Using Lambdas, Using method references. There were below examples used:

```
Predicate<String> ref = String::isEmpty;
```

Java uses the parameter supplied at runtime as the instance on which isEmpty is called. This is allowed because isEmpty() is an instance method in String class and doesn't take any parameter.

My question is, why does it shows compile error when I use the below line of code:

```
Supplier<Integer> ref2 = Random::nextInt;
```

After all, nextInt() is an instance method in Random class just like isEmpty() in String class and it doesn't take parameter either.

Comment: `String::isEmpty` takes a String as an argument. By the same logic, `Random::nextInt` needs a Random as an argument. So it would be a Function, not a Supplier.

Comment: In `Random::nextInt`, on which Random instance are you calling nextInt?  What seed was used to initialize it?  nextInt is not a static method, so you have to pass the nextInt method of an existing Random instance.  Just like you can’t write `Random.nextInt()` in code.

Comment: You can do `new Random()::nextInt` instead.

Answer (score 9):

`Random::nextInt` is an instance method, so it needs an instance of `Random` in order to be called. Just like you can't call `String::isEmpty` without a String. That's why `String::isEmpty` is a match for `Predicate<String>`: it takes a String as an argument and returns a boolean.

Similarly, `Random::nextInt` needs an instance of Random as an argument, and returns an int. So it could be used as a `Function<Random, Integer>`; but not a `Supplier<Integer>`, because it cannot be called without arguments.

Alternatively, if you have an instance of Random, you can use a reference to the `nextInt` method of *that particular instance* as a Supplier.

```
Random random = new Random();
Supplier<Integer> randomIntSupplier = random::nextInt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I understand it a little better now.